# Vbs script opening a program on a message box

Tags: vbscript

I need a vbs script with a message box that opens iexplorer when I click yes, and close the msg box when I click no. Thanks, I am new to programming, and need help. Thank you.

Comment: wdym? i am confused

Comment: oh i have made an attempt, very many actually. i just have not posted it as i am very bad and starting from scratch is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a shoot for this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Answer,ws,Site
Site = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
Title = "Open iexplore.exe"
Answer = MsgBox("Did you want to open iexplore.exe ?",VbQuestion+VbYesNo,Title)
If Answer = vbYes Then
    set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run("iexplore.exe" &" "& Site)
End If
Wscript.Quit()
```

Comment: oof ok, so is there a way to make it open to a specific site, sorry for the late notice :(

Comment: @Sbognar if this answer helped you, you should [accept it !](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
response = MsgBox("Would you like to open Internet Explorer?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbYes Then
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("iexplore")
End If
```